# Implementing bidirectional pipe on Linux

Tags: c, linux, pipe

There is an interactive command line utility (Samba smbclient) which we want to execute in our program. smbclient is like a typical interactive ftp client in the way that you feed a command to it (after its prompt) and it accesses the network share and returns you the result. For our program, we want to enter one command, retrieve the result, enter next command, and so on..

This is our sample program. `/root/testfifo` is a fifo that was already created in bash via `mkfifo`.

```
int main()
{
    const char *cmd = "smbclient //machine/share \
    -U domain/user%pwd  > /root/testfifo";

    FILE *out = popen(cmd, "w");
    if (!out)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Write the command to smbclient via 1st pipe
    fputs("ls\n", out);
    fflush(out);

    // Read the result from smbclient via 2nd pipe
    FILE *in = fopen("/root/testfifo", "r");
     
    if (!in)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    char buf[1000];
    // Pending here..
    fgets(buf, 1000, in);
    
    fclose(in);
    pclose(out);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The thing is, the program is pending on the `fgets` line waiting for input from `in`. However, if I remove the 2nd pipe `in`, run our program first, and open a separate terminal to read from the same pipe (e.g., `tail -f /root/testfifo`), it's not blocking and prints the correct result from smbclient.

Why is that?

Comment: The second popen needs to be a regular fopen.

Comment: @DanD. It's a typo. I've corrected it. fopen or ifstream, neither fixes this issue.

Comment: `string`? `cmd.c_str()`?!  This looks like C++, written in the style of C.  The code should either be modified to actually be C, or you should apply a C++ tag.

Comment: Unrelated style suggestion: use C's implicit string literal concatentation instead of line joining.  The latter is not idiomatic anywhere except in long macro definitions.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, this is not a language question and that's why i didn't tag c or c++ here. Someone added it. Let me remove it.

Comment: @EricZ, the question *should* bear an appropriate language tag.  That detail matters.  Since it indeed does appear to be C++ (as the prose also indicates), I have added that tag.

Comment: @John, John.. I don't see why particular language matters here. And if you tag w/ C++ people will question why not use C++ style I/O streams, all those stuff.. diverting the real concerns here.

Comment: Yes, people may ask why you are not using more idiomatic C++.  And that's relevant, especially if your objective is to solve the problem.  Of course, there's so little C++ in it that you could consider just converting the code and tag to C if you don't want to deal with such questions.  Either way, the source language is unquestionably relevant context for the question.  Ironically, by omitting a language tag, you seem to have invited just the kind of tangential discussion you hoped to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily so easy to programmatically operate a user interface designed for humans.  Text-based UIs are easier, generally, but you appear to have stumbled upon one of the gotchas: a C or C++ program's standard streams are *fully buffered* if the program determines that they are not connected to an interactive device (which usually means a terminal).  Ditto for files opened via `fopen()` and `popen()`.

Your program depends on its own streams to be line-buffered or unbuffered.  You can arrange that via [`setvbuf()` or `setlinebuf()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html):

```
    setlinebuf(outpipe);
    setlinebuf(inpipe);
```

But that might not be enough.  If `smbclient` uses stdio functions for reading commands and emitting output then it will have buffering on its side as well, and that's outside your control.

What you really need is a pseudo-terminal in which to run smbclient, so that it acts as if it were running interactively.  You could roll your own, but this sort of thing is *exactly* what [libexpect](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libexpect.3.html) is all about.  I would suggest reworking your program around using this library to launch and communicate with `smbclient`.  As a bonus, you will not have to manage a fifo.

Comment: `libexpect` is an eye-opener to me. You have my +1 and acceptance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be because smbclient is doing some kind of buffering, so that the result get flushed out only when you do `pclose(outpipe);`

This version with `cat` works:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
#define cmd "{ sleep 10; cat; } > /tmp/testfifo"

    FILE* outpipe = popen(cmd, "w");
    if (!outpipe)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Write the command to smbclient via 1st pipe
    fputs("Message sent\n", outpipe);
    fflush(outpipe);

    // Read the result from smbclient via 2nd pipe
    FILE* inpipe = fopen("/tmp/testfifo", "r");
     
    if (!inpipe)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    char buf[1000];
    // Pending here..
    fgets(buf, 1000, inpipe);
    printf("This is the message received : [%s]\n", buf);
    
    pclose(inpipe);
    pclose(outpipe);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You made a point. I suspected the same and even tried `pclose(outpipe)` first before opening the 2nd pipe/file. Still doesn't solve.

Comment: Closing the pipe actually works. But the program in the other end of the pipe is gone. So it doesn't fit well in our send-receive-send-receive model. A very good point!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this has something to do w/ the I/O buffering inside smbclient (or any other application that has the similar buffering).

To work around it,

```
const char *cmd =
"stdbuf -oL smbclient //machine/share \
    -U domain/user%pwd  > /root/testfifo";
```

Reference for further readers:
[Turn-off-buffering-in-pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)